# Two forms on the same page - errors messages visibles just in first one

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two steps forms on different modal each.
Three steps on first one (#form1) and the same on second one (#form2).
All **inputs and elements with different names and ID**.
Links with  validation pages (one by step)are working. My problem is just errors messages don't appear on second form. I made the verification with  error containers id (one id by form too).
An idea why ?
I try to resolve by coding a array2 of errors for form2 but no error messages visible.

```
 $(".step1").click(function() {      

      var data = {
        'data1'   : jQuery("input[name=data1]:checked", "#forml").val(),
        'data2' : jQuery('#data2').val(),
        'data3'  : jQuery('#data3').val(),
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
        url : '/mySite/parsers/check.php',
        method : 'POST',
        type    : 'POST',
        data : data,
        success : function(data){
      if (data != 'passed') {
        jQuery('#list_errors').html(data);
        }
     if (data.result == 'passed') {
        $(".frm").hide("fast");
        $("#step2").show("slow");
        $(".open1").css("display","none");
        $(".open2").css("display","inline-block");

      }
    },
    error : function(){
        alert('no working.'); }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Probleme not solved. forms has différent name and id. All inputs have diferent id and name. Same for errors  messages containers.
Nobody can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're outputting errors on a `div` using `ID`. `ID` of `DIVs` should be unique on a single page.

What jQuery does is, it updates the **first** `DIV` with `list_errors` ID and leaves the second one which is in second modal as it is.

### Solution:

Use different `IDs` for each or use `class` of the `DIV` and access it with `parent()` or `child()` jQuery function.

Comment: I had :<span class="bg-danger text-center " id="list_errors></span>
Just try : <span class="bg-danger text-center list_errors "></span> Not working too. Thanks to your attention.

Comment: Change `list_errors` for second modal and that should fix the issue. Don't forget to update jQuery with second `ID`.

Comment: more détails about the bug : second form validates just one time. If I enter a just variable in one field, when I tryed to validate by clicking an another time  nothing appen...

Comment: That's because of the same `ID` of elements. Keep different `ID` of each element (form,DIV, etc...) and have separate jQuery written for the same.

Comment: Sorry but I reiterate, every element had différent name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention about in which form you need to display error. Also change `id='list_errors'` to `class='list_errors'` because its not good to use same id in one page.

$(".step1").click(function() {

```
  var data = {
    'data1'   : jQuery("input[name=data1]:checked", "#forml").val(),
    'data2' : jQuery('#data2').val(),
    'data3'  : jQuery('#data3').val(),
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
    url : '/mySite/parsers/check.php',
    method : 'POST',
    type    : 'POST',
    data : data,
    success : function(data){
  if (data != 'passed') {
    $(this).find('.list_errors').html(data);
    }
 if (data.result == 'passed') {
    $(".frm").hide("fast");
    $("#step2").show("slow");
    $(".open1").css("display","none");
    $(".open2").css("display","inline-block");

  }
},
error : function(){
    alert('no working.'); }
    });

});
```

Comment: <span class="bg-danger text-center list_errors"></span>. Not working. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: just try "$("#form1").find('.list_errors).html(data);" too... but no chance.